# Node.js File System - Saving unique file names

Tags: javascript, node.js, while-loop, save

I'm using Node File System to save uploaded images, using a while loop to check for existing file names, incrementing++ until there's a unique file name.

The code is not working, getting `SyntaxError: Illegal break statement` errors for the placement of my `break;` line, as well as the while loop never properly reading my `fs.exists()` function within the loop.

Am I doing something completely wrong here logically? Is there an easier way to ensure `fs.writeFile()` doesn't overwrite existing files?

Code:

```
  var fileExist = true;
  var fileName = req.files.files[0].name.substr(0, req.files.files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.')) || req.files.files[0].name;
  var fileType = req.files.files[0].name.split('.').pop();
  var fileNumber = 1;

  while (fileExist) {

    fileNumber_str = fileNumber.toString(); 

    var current = fileName + fileNumber_str + '.' + fileType;

    fs.exists( __dirname + "/uploads/" + current, function(exists){

        if (exists) {
            fileNumber++;
        }

        if (!exists) {

            var newPath = __dirname + "/uploads/" + current;
            fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
                res.send('saved');
            });

            break;
        }

    });

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to break out of the callback of fs.exists, which is indeed illegal. It might be easier to use fs.existsSync

Ex:

```
while (fileExist) {

    fileNumber_str = fileNumber.toString(); 

    var current = fileName + fileNumber_str + '.' + fileType;


    if (fs.existsSync(__dirname + "/uploads/" + current)) {
        fileNumber++;
    } else {
        var newPath = __dirname + "/uploads/" + current;
        fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
            res.send('saved');
        });

        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**

Your code is using the async version of fs.exists. You need to use the sync version fs.existsSync for your loop to work.

**Warning**

Storing uploaded files using the name provided by the request is a bad idea as it allows a hacker to put in relative paths and potentially store files in places you would not want them to end up.

Equally it's a bad idea to allow those uploaded files to be downloaded using a path in the querystring. A hacker could write this: http://example.com/download?fileName=../../somethingnotexposed/

Comment: I think this is an excellent ancillary point but I don't know if it answers the question....

Comment: Excellent response, but the fs.existsSync() still isn't firing within the loop, when I generated a random number for the file name instead of using the uploaded name.

Comment: adotout's answer was similar, but the code they posted correctly executed fs.existssync within the loop. I am incorporating your critique of file name use by generating random numbers instead - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Checking if a file exists before opening is an anti-pattern that
>   leaves you vulnerable to race conditions: another process can remove
>   the file between the calls to fs.exists() and fs.open()

You can use fsu module https://github.com/velocityzen/fsu